# Error occurs when I use pyenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, homebrew, pyenv

When I tried to use pyenv install, an error occurred. I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

```
DennisdeMacBook-Pro:~ Dennis$ pyenv install 3.5.2
Downloading Python-3.5.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.5.2...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.6 using python-build 20160130)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/mj/mqpslr496bs1b2rwq3hxkm1w0000gn/T/python-build.20160810223509.6857
Results logged to /var/folders/mj/mqpslr496bs1b2rwq3hxkm1w0000gn/T/python-build.20160810223509.6857.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/var/folders/mj/mqpslr496bs1b2rwq3hxkm1w0000gn/T/python-build.20160810223509.6857/Python-3.5.2/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    ensurepip._main()
  File "/private/var/folders/mj/mqpslr496bs1b2rwq3hxkm1w0000gn/T/python-build.20160810223509.6857/Python-3.5.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 209, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/private/var/folders/mj/mqpslr496bs1b2rwq3hxkm1w0000gn/T/python-build.20160810223509.6857/Python-3.5.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 116, in bootstrap
    _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/private/var/folders/mj/mqpslr496bs1b2rwq3hxkm1w0000gn/T/python-build.20160810223509.6857/Python-3.5.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 40, in _run_pip
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Xcode:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I have xcode installed but I still get this error. Mac OS Mojave (10.14).

Comment: This is due to missing headers in `/include`. See [this response](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1219#issuecomment-429331397) and the rest of the issue thread.